# Change DatePickerDialog valid dates color in Android

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

I have a DatePickerDialoge in my Fragment, I have set its min and max valid dates.

```
datePickerDialog.setMinDate(calenderMinObj);
datePickerDialog.setMaxDate(calendarMaxObj);
```

It is working fine and valid dates are in bold

[image]

But I want to change the colour of all valid dates to green so user can easily understand. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add/override style to your DateTime Fragment. Please follow the below-mentioned link to achieve the desired result:-

https://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2019/09/android-datepicker-dialog-styling-kotlin.html